# ASP.NET Core Web API send 400 Bad Request for request client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpclient, bad-request

I have two ASP.NET Core Web API projects called `app.account` and `core.account`. I the both projects have some testing API endpoint like this.

In `app.account`:

```
namespace app.account.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class SubInteractiveStatementController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("account/istatement")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test(Test cif)
        {
            return Ok("hello gamma");
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string cif { get; set; }
}
```

In `core.account`:

```
namespace core.account.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class CasaDetailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("account/istatement")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test(Test cif)
        {
            return Ok("hello gamma");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling the above API endpoint throughout the client side like this:

```
try {
  CommonResponse commonResponse = new();

  var data_ = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
  var buffer_ = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data_);
  var byteContent_ = new ByteArrayContent(buffer_);
  byteContent_.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

  //string _urls = "http://localhost:5088/account/istatement";
  string _urls = "http://localhost:5035/account/istatement";
  var responses_ = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_urls, byteContent_);

  if (responses_.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    Console.WriteLine("[GetPrimeryAccount] Response: Success");
    string body = await responses_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var rtns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < CommonResponse > (body);
  }
} catch (global::System.Exception) {

  throw;
}
```

http://localhost:5088/account/istatement is the app.account API endpoint and http://localhost:5035/account/istatement is the core.account API endpoint.

When I call the `app.account`, I'm getting the following error.

> { StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
> {
> Date: Wed, 19 Oct 2022 08:43:21 GMT
> Server: Kestrel
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> }}

But it's properly calling the `core.account` API endpoint.

Both URL's are correct, I checked both endpoints using Postman, and that worked properly.

What could be the reason for this? Could it be a HTTP version issue? How can I determine the exact reason for this? Please help. Thanks

Comment: There is `HttpClientJsonExtensions` in `System.Net.Http.Json` package which has nice `PostAsJsonAsync` method ...

Comment: @Selvin I tried, but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in a part that you have not shared with us.
Please share both of the API project's `startup.cs` here. For a hint, If you are using any custom header validation middleware, make sure to pass those header values properly. Otherwise, that may cause to occur 400 Bad Request.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseMiddleware<YourcCustomHeaderValidationClass>(); // Custom header validation

    app.UseRouting();
}
```

Compare the both `startp.cs` files and you will be able to identify the problem there.

Comment: nice catch, this was the reason

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the request

Instead of manually composing the data as byte array content, you can use the [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=net-6.0) class

```
await _httpClient.PostAsync(_urls, new StringContent(data_, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

If you want to shorten it even more, there's a [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh944521(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(_urls, data_);
```

Comment: I tried as above, but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the reason for this? Could it be a HTTP version issue?
> How can I determine the exact reason for this?

Well, you are certainly getting the error because of your `[Route("account/istatement")]` route. You cannot use [`multiple route attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#multiple-attribute-routes) for same action, not matter even if the controller are different even if the projcts are different within the same solution.

Remember your [`route attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#combining-attribute-routes) should be `unique` within the solution if you defined it following this fashion `[Route("account/istatement")]`.

**Solution:**

If you comment either of this [`route attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#combining-attribute-routes) from either of the controller it would work. Or you can use the `route attribute` globally on your controller level.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I changed it, just added this code sample for verify code, level there is no differentiate. but still getting the same issue

Comment: Then of course, we are missing something which you haven't shared, you could check the investigation example on the updated answer.

Comment: In addition, since you haven't shared anything about your `token` related  issue. So `400` is not feasible.